# Cant fetch array from server side

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I want to get some data from a php script to my html page. They array $UniqueNames has a value on the server side, but nothing seems to happen when i use json_encode on the html page, the console.log returns an empty array (BilderID). Any suggestions?

code:

```
<script>
var BilderID = [];
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#SubmitBild').on('click', function () {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        var ins = document.getElementById('Myfilefield').files.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
            form_data.append("Bilder[]", document.getElementById('Myfilefield').files[x]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Includes/Bildhantering.php', // point to server-side PHP script
            dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#msg').html(response); // display success response from 
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $('#msg').html(response); // display error response from the PHP script
            }
        });

        BilderID = <?php echo json_encode($UniqueNames); ?>

        console.log(BilderID);

    });
});
</script>
```

Php:

```
$UniqueNames = array();    

for($i=0;$i<count($file_array);$i++)
{
    if($file_array[$i]['error']){
        echo $phpFileUploadErrors[$file_array[$i]['error']];
    } else {
        $extensions = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
        $file_ext = explode('.',$file_array[$i]['name']);
        $file_ext = end($file_ext);

        if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)){
            echo "Invalid file extension!";
        } else {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$file_ext;
            $UniqueNames[] = $fileNameNew;

            move_uploaded_file($file_array[$i]['tmp_name'], 'Bilder/'.$fileNameNew);
            echo $phpFileUploadErrors[$file_array[$i]['error']];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dataType should be set to json - not text

Comment: @treyBake still nothing.

Comment: His not outputting any JSON from the PHP file...

Comment: Your mixing server-side with front-end/DOM, it wont work they way you've set it up.

Comment: oh wait ... why are you echoing the PHP variable in your jquery script? use response ..

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to remove the datatype specifier, echo out the array in php and receive it inside the success method:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'Includes/Bildhantering.php', // point to server-side PHP script
            //dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
              BilderID = response;
              console.log(BilderID);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log("error:");
            }
        });
```

i mean, why use "datatype" if javascript figures it out anyway?